# Changes aren't being saved by the edit page - Cocoon Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, cocoon-gem

Pardon me if my language isn't correct, I'm relatively new to Rails and Ruby.

I'm using Cocoon to select from a list of currently existing options in a nested model, but the options I choose never end up saving. I'm almost certain it has to do with how I've modeled the controller, but I'm not certain where the error is.

I'll post the pertinent code here.

Model Files:

```
# product.rb
module Almacenear
  class Product < Almacenear::ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category, optional: true, inverse_of: :product
    has_and_belongs_to_many :shops, inverse_of: :product
  end
end

#shop.rb
module Almacenear
  class Shop < Almacenear::ApplicationRecord
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :reject_if => :all_blank
  end
end
```

---

Controller File:

```
#shops_controller.rb
module Almacenear
  module Grocermenu
    class ShopsController < Almacenear::ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_grocer!
      before_action :find_shop, only: %i[edit update show]
      helper  Almacenear::Grocermenu::Engine.routes.url_helpers
      include Almacenear::Grocermenu::Engine.routes.url_helpers


      def update
        if @shop.update(shop_params)
          redirect_to almacenear_grocermenu.shop_path
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end

      protected

      def shop_params
        params.require(:shop).permit(:business_name, :location,
                                     products_attributes: [:id, :name, :category_id,
                                                           :product_type, :description, :measurement_unit,
                                                           :image, :other_id, :ean,
                                                           :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size,
                                                           :image_updated_at, :img_url_web, :_destroy])
      end

      def find_shop
        @shop = Almacenear::Shop.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

Views:

```
#_addproduct.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @shop, url: url do |f| %>
  <div id='products'>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :products do |product| %>
      <%= render 'product_fields', :f => product %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association '+', f, :products, class:"btn btn-success" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.button :submit, value: 'Enviar', class: 'btn-success' %>
<% end %>

# _product_fields.html.erb
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <%= f.select :id, Almacenear::Product.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true } %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association '-', f , class:"btn btn-danger"%>
</div>
```

The error I'd get is that once it tries to load `almacenear_grocermenu.shop_path`, it would state that:

```
Couldn't find Almacenear::Product with ID=15 for Almacenear::Shop with ID=1
```

i.e. it would try to display the product with ID = 15 associated with Almacenear::Shop before it would save it to Almacenear::Shop's list of product_ids. And just to check, if I had update redirect to `almacenear_grocermenu.shops_path`, i.e. to the list of the shops associated with the currently logged in Grocer, there'd be no error but also no change to the list of products associated with that shop in particular.

I also originally tested changing the line in the controller from `products_attributes: [...]` to `:product_ids => []` and nothing was saved either. This was a leftover from when I used Simple_Form's **association**, along with Checkboxes, before I began using the **Cocoon Gem**. The error in that case would be that it would just simply ignore the changes requested.

Finally, I wanted to point out that the problem is saving the association between a shop and products. The partial **addproducts** is accompanied by another partial, used to edit the shop's own fields, like it's name and address, and when changes are made to this they are indeed saved to the shop's values.

Sorry for the long post, I just had detail my process as best I could, and it's my first post so I hope it's not too poorly worded. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no relation to product in your shop, or is that copy/paste error? How is the association declared? Since you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, it might be necessary to make the join-table explicit.